# How to get button to add text to input form

Tags: javascript, input

Forgive me I

```js
function addText() {
var input = document.getElementById('something');
input.value = input.value +'URGENT PLEASE READ';
}
```

```html
<form name="frm1" action="?" onsubmit="addText()">
<p> Subject </p><input type="text" name="Subject" size="40" id="something" onsubmit="addText()"maxlength="30" />

                     <p>Message</p>
<textarea id="angryarea" name="Message" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>     
                    
<input type="submit" value="MAKE URGENT" id="URGENT"/>

                    </form>
```

am very new to JS and I am attempting to create a button that adds the words "URGENT PLEASE READ" to the subject of a message; however, the following code simply clears my subject head.  Thank you in advance,

Comment: That's because the form is submitted, and the page **reloads** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you wanted a separate button for make urgent and submit - if so you can do it like this

```js
function addText() {
    var input = document.getElementById('something');
    input.value = input.value + 'URGENT PLEASE READ';
}
```

```html
<form name="frm1" action="?" onsubmit="addText()">
  <p> Subject </p><input type="text" name="Subject" size="40" id="something" maxlength="30" />

  <p>Message</p>
  <textarea id="angryarea" name="Message" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea> 


  <button type="button" id="URGENT" onclick="addText()">MAKE URGENT</button>
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use proper event handlers on the forms `submit` event, and prevent the form from submitting, otherwise the page just reloads, and the changed value is lost.

```js
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var input = document.getElementById('something');
  input.value = input.value + 'URGENT PLEASE READ';
});
```

```html
<form name="frm1" action="?" id="myForm">
  <p> Subject </p>
  <input type="text" name="Subject" size="40" id="something" maxlength="30" />

  <p>Message</p>
  <textarea id="angryarea" name="Message" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>

  <input type="submit" value="MAKE URGENT" id="URGENT" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a Checkbox?

```html
<form name="frm1" action="?">
    <p> Subject </p>
    <input type="text" name="Subject" size="40" id="something" maxlength="30" />

    <p>Message</p>
    <textarea id="angryarea" name="Message" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
    
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Urgent" /> Make urgent
    
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```